# Error calling PutEx with a filtered array

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adsi

If I call `PutEx` on an `adsi` object in PowerShell everything works as expected:

```
$values = @("xyz", "abc" )
$user = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=someone,CN=Users,DC=acme,DC=com"
$user.PutEx($ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE, "altsecurityidentities", $values)
$user.SetInfo()
```

Howver, if I do the same thing but filtering the values with `Where-Object`, I get an error:

```
$values = @("xyz", "abc" )
$filtered = @($values | ? { $_.startsWith("x") })
$user = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=someone,CN=Users,DC=acme,DC=com"
$user.PutEx($ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE, "altsecurityidentities", $filtered)
$user.SetInfo()
```

The error is: `Exception calling "PutEx" with "3" argument(s): "Unspecified error`.

What's the difference in the two cases?

Comment: The only difference I see between the two samples you give is that the first tries to delete an "alt security identity" for "xyz" and "abc", whilst the seconds tries to delete two "alt security indentities" for just "xyz". Both arguments are of type object[], so I can't see a problem!

Comment: I can't see a problem either, yet one works and the other does not :)
By the way, why should the second try to delete *two* altSecurityIdentities? Shouldn't that be an array of just one value?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned them the wrong way round! You are right, the second should give you an array of just one value. Just for interest, what happens if you put the filtered value in twice?

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to iterate through your `$filtered` objects as follows:

```
$values = @("xyz", "abc" )
$filtered = @($values | ? { $_.startsWith("x") })
foreach($item in $filtered){
    $user = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=someone,CN=Users,DC=acme,DC=com"
    $user.PutEx($ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE, "altsecurityidentities", $item)
    $user.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: `$item` should actually be `@($item)`, because `PutEx` expects an array. That does not work either. However, I'm using a similar workaround, but I would really like to try to understand the reason why I'm getting this strange error.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a reason why your code should fail, [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746504.aspx).

```
$values = @("xyz", "abc", "xref", "xtup")
$values.GetType().fullname
System.Object[]

$filtered = @($values | ?{$_.StartsWith("x")})
$filtered.GetType().fullname
System.Object[]

$values = @("xyz", "abc")
$filtered = @($values | ?{$_.StartsWith("x")})
$filtered.GetType().fullname
System.Object[]

$filtered = [System.Array]($values | ?{$_.StartsWith("x")})
$filtered.GetType().fullname
System.Object[]
```

The only doubt I have is, if it is expecting an array of strings because all the examples I have checked seem to indicate so. What would happen if you tried:

```
$filtered = [String[]]($values | ?{$_.StartsWith("x")})
$filtered.GetType().fullname
System.String[]
```

And see how that works?

**PS:** Can't post a comment yet so, had to add a reply.